# Alternative option for select * from

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, odbc, query

In the Excel database query we will use the below syntax to define a reference value

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:Z500] where Dept = 'IT'
```

In the above case I am taking the **Dept** value `IT` as a reference to get all `IT` related data. So we are defining the reference value here as `IT`.

My question is instead of defining as `IT` can I make a list of values in a column in the same excel file as a reference.

P.S : I don't want to keep on keying in the reference values here. Just by defining the sheet name and the cell range of the values I want to get the related data.

Like `Sheet2 A3:A100`

So that just by updating the values in `Sheet2 A3:A100` I can get the related values. I need not have to open and edit the SQL statement every time.

Comment: Can you select from two tables like `SELECT Src.* FROM [Sheet1$A1:Z500] Src, [Sheet2!$A3:$A100] Criteria where Src.Dept = Criteria.columnName and Criteria.columnName <> ''` ?

Comment: @Kenneth I tried the above method but the SQL Says **Cannot represent SQL. Ignore anyway?**. If I press OK then error message shows that `Cannot find the table [Sheet2!$A3:$A100]`.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't know the exact syntax for Excel database query, so probably you will need to fix my syntax things.  What I meant was, if you would like to match a list of criteria, you will need to join the two tables by `select` the two tables and join them at the `where` clause.